# How to triger a custom event in the app component in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, router-outlet

In the `ionic` project I want to change the varaible `showSearchBox` `dynamically` that's why. I have used a custom event `searchBox` which is triggered by an another component but the `searchBoxShow()` never called. So how can I fix this issue so that I can trigger a function dynamically in the `app.component` which will update the variable `searchBox` dynamically.

Here is my `app.component.html` code.

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet style="margin-top: 50px; bottom: 0px;" *ngIf="showSearchBox" (searchBox)="searchBoxShow()"></ion-router-outlet>
  <ion-router-outlet *ngIf="!showSearchBox" (searchBox)="searchBoxShow()" ></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

And the code of the `other.component.ts`.

```
@Output('searchBox') showSearchBox = new EventEmitter();

ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.showSearchBox.emit();
}
```